# to transfer files in linux fedora 12 by giving password at command prompt

Tags: linux, rsync

I am fully aware that this question has been asked many times but I cant able to find any solution which satisy my requirement.

**Task ->** I need to transfer files from machine A to machineB and remotely execute scripts on Machine B. Due to my limitation I **cant** able to use keygen, expect utility or any other utility which requires to install packages.  To Transfer the file I need to give password **and I want to give password in  Url**. as this will run inside bash script and requires no user interference .

**My investigation**- I thought of using scp but realise, its not possible to give password at command prompt. So i wondering , if there is any other alternative from rsync .

below is the small attempt

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
USER="bob"
RSYNC_PASSWORD="blue"
MACHINE_B="192.168.200.2"
if ping -c 1 -W 1 $MACHINE_B
then
 echo "There is machine b as well"
 echo " cheking to transfer file to machine b"
    rsync lol.sh  192.168.200.2:/home/bob/
fi
```

Thanks and regards,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried various option mentioned above ,, but unfortunately none of them works in my case. But I would like to thanks everyone for helping me and surely I have learned  few new things specially rsync.
In my case, I have to rely on ssh keys to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

From the rsync man page:

```
   Some modules on the remote daemon may require authentication. If so, you will receive a password prompt when you connect. You can avoid the  password
   prompt  by  setting  the  environment variable RSYNC_PASSWORD to the password you want to use or using the --password-file option. This may be useful
   when scripting rsync.
```

Comment: Hi Stephane, Thanks for reply,  but since I cant fiddle around with  the setting of systems at this point, I am unable to make any changes. Secondly, I can provide the password of machineB  and I am not concerned with security at this junction.

Comment: Are you saying you're unable to set the `RSYNC_PASSWORD` variable, or that you can't use the `--password-file` option?

Comment: @hometoast,  I have tried to change RYSNC_PASSWORD vis bash script and run the command but it doesnt work . I will post a small code  in my question

Comment: But yes , I can provide the password of machine B

Comment: I have no idea about --password-file option

Comment: write your passwd in a file e.g. mypasswdfile and add `--password-file=mypasswdfile` to your rsync command

Comment: @Stephane , I have tried to give command like this in my bash script           rsync -a -v lol.sh  USER@192.168.200.2:/home/bob/ --password-file=mypasswdfile                                                       but I am getting error like  "The --password-file option may only be used when accessing an rsync daemon.2